# Show flutter overlay according to different variables

Tags: flutter, build, state, riverpod

I have a flutter screen called TestMain which has a scaffold and white background. The scaffolds body is supposed to change if certain events happen. The events are stored as a boolean. There is "isLocked" and "isPaused" which get emitted by a Riverpod Stream Provider and "isCheating" which changes when Applifecyle events get triggered. All of the three booleans are stored as Riverpod StateProviders, because of its global accesibility.

This is is my "isCheatingProvider":
`final isCheatingProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) => false);`
The "isPausedProvider" and "isLockedProvider" are the same.

This is the TestMain screen

```
class TestMain extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const TestMain({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<TestMain> createState() => _TestMainScreenState();
}

class _TestMainScreenState extends ConsumerState<TestMain>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    final isCheating = ref.watch(isCheatingProvider.notifier);

    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        await sendCheatingAttempt(ref);
        setState(() {
          isCheating.state = true;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        await sendCheatingAttempt(ref);
        setState(() {
          isCheating.state = true;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        await sendCheatingAttempt(ref);
        setState(() {
          isCheating.state = true;
        });
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Item> items = ref.watch(itemsProvider);
    final AsyncValue<dynamic> wsTestListenerMessage =
        ref.watch(testListenerProvider);

    final isLocked = ref.watch(isLockedProvider.notifier);
    final isPaused = ref.watch(isPausedProvider.notifier);
    final isCheating = ref.watch(isCheatingProvider.notifier);

    wsTestListenerMessage.when(
      loading: () => {},
      error: (err, stack) => print('Test State Error: $err'),
      data: (message) async {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
          if (message["lock"] == true) {
            isLocked.state = true;
          }
          if (message["unlock"] == true) {
            isLocked.state = false;
          }
          if (message["paused"] == true) {
            isPaused.state = true;
          }
          if (message["resumed"] == true) {
            isPaused.state = false;
          }
        });
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: isPaused.state
              ? const ErrorOverlay(text: 'paused')
              : isLocked.state || isCheating.state
                  ? const ErrorOverlay(text: 'cheating')
                  : const TestView()),
    );
  }
}
```

But it doesnt work. No matter what I do. I added the `Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {}` around the if-statements, because it complained about changing the provider in build method, I use setState() in `didChangeAppLifecycleState()`, but can't use it in the listener, because the listener would called over and over again. It shouldnt be openend more than once.

(ErrorOverlay is a custom widget that just shows the text in big red letters, in the center)

Answer (score 0):

- remove the `setState`, this will do nothing
- for set a state use `ref.read(provider.notifier).state`
- for watch use `ref.watch(isCheatingProvider)`

By changing all that it is good by testing on my side :

```
final isCheatingProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) => false);

class TestMain extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const TestMain({key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<TestMain> createState() => _TestMainScreenState();
}

class _TestMainScreenState extends ConsumerState<TestMain>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    final isCheating = ref.read(isCheatingProvider.notifier);

    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        isCheating.state = true;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        isCheating.state = true;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        isCheating.state = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isCheating = ref.watch(isCheatingProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: isCheating ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: isCheating ? Text('cheat') : Text(' good')
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesnt work. First of all, if I print the message emitted from the Stream, every message get printed twice and if cheating gets triggered, the cheating screen appears for a milli second and disappears. After that every more events get print to the console

Comment: The problem must come from listen + future. Normally you shouldn't need it. If you just want to have a provider B that depends on A you can simply do the following https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it solved my problem completely! @Pierre Bouttier

Comment: I do have another question regarding the previous one (which works perfectly now). Before navigating to the TestMain screen it checks a state from an API. If state == 4, the Paused Overlay is supposed to be enabled immediately when the user gets navigated to TestMain. I set ref.read(isPausedProvider.notifier).state to true and then navigate to the TestMain screen, but if I watch the Provider again, its value is false. Setting it looks like this: 
      `ref.read(isPausedProvider.notifier).state = true;`

Comment: maybe it was disposed so it's value came back to false. Try remove the autodispose if you need it for the life of the app

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using `StateProvider`. To watch `StateNotifier` you should use

```dart
final isCheating = ref.watch(isCheatingProvider);
```

and to change provider use

```dart
ref.read(productSortTypeProvider.notifier).state = value;
```

So you have to change all provider related code.

```dart
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

  final isCheatingNotifier = ref.read(isCheatingProvider.notifier);

  switch (state) {
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      await sendCheatingAttempt(ref);
      isCheatingNotifier.state = true;
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      await sendCheatingAttempt(ref);
      isCheatingNotifier.state = true;
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      await sendCheatingAttempt(ref);
      isCheatingNotifier.state = true;
      break;
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final List<Item> items = ref.watch(itemsProvider);
  final AsyncValue<dynamic> wsTestListenerMessage =
  ref.watch(testListenerProvider);

  final isLocked = ref.watch(isLockedProvider);
  final isPaused = ref.watch(isPausedProvider);
  final isCheating = ref.watch(isCheatingProvider);

  wsTestListenerMessage.when(
    loading: () => {},
    error: (err, stack) => print('Test State Error: $err'),
    data: (message) async {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
        final isLockedNotifier = ref.read(isLockedProvider.notifier);
        final isPausedNotifier = ref.read(isPausedProvider.notifier);

        if (message["lock"] == true) {
          isLockedNotifier.state = true;
        }
        if (message["unlock"] == true) {
          isLockedNotifier.state = false;
        }
        if (message["paused"] == true) {
          isPausedNotifier.state = true;
        }
        if (message["resumed"] == true) {
          isPausedNotifier.state = false;
        }
      });
    },
  );

  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: SafeArea(
        child: isPaused
            ? const ErrorOverlay(text: 'paused')
            : isLocked || isCheating
            ? const ErrorOverlay(text: 'cheating')
            : const TestView()),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesnt work. First of all, if I print the message emitted from the Stream, every message get printed twice and if cheating gets triggered, the cheating screen appears for a milli second and disappears. After that every more events get print to the console